# SSRS HTML rendering

Tags: html, email, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I need data driven subscription on a report in ssrs 2008 that put html or mhtml into email message. The reason is to have opportunity to view reports in mobile devices without additional applications except email, thats why I cant use pdf or excel format.

When I convert report into html4.0 file by clicking on “Export” button everything is fine report looks exactly as template and there are enough space between pages.

[image: manualy converted report]

But when ssrs creates email with html file report pages slides over each other. When I zoom out report it increase the distance between pages. 
[image: report from email]

I figure out the problem. Manualy created report has such a style for every report page

```
<div style="WIDTH:100%;" class="ap">
```

but sent html has:

```
  <div style="HEIGHT: 100%; WIDTH:100%;" class="ap">
```

If I manually comment  “HEIGHT: 100%” pages become in readable style. 
So Imy question is how to set up ssrs to create html without “HEIGHT: 100%”.
I really don't want to create external html processor to update html generated by SSRS.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: have you found a solution for this? I am stuck on the same problem

Comment: unfortunately I haven't

Answer (score 0):

have you tried making the div style="HEIGHT: 100%" part of you style for each page, but maybe using different values (instead of 100%) to see if you attain the same result? It may be that 100% is too much but a smaller % may be ok and including the height in your style should ensure that the Height:100% is not embedded at export. Hope this helps.

Comment: 100% is to small, 200% is ok, but the question is "how to set up ssrs to change this style"

Comment: hhmm, have you tried using XSLT to transform the report contents on export? This might help (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159716(v=sql.90).aspx). I use them in our place to reformat the data, they can be tricky but are very powerful for this stuff.